# bare-metal server vs cloud server vs on-prem server?

Tags: server, virtualization

I am trying to understand the difference between bare-metal servers and cloud servers. I am referring to the following document,[blog](https://www.servers.com/news/blog/bare-metal-vs-cloud-servers-what-s-the-difference).

I understand that Amazon EC2(which is all the rage) is an example of cloud servers, is there any benefit of bare-metal servers over cloud servers like Amazon EC2? In what scenario will we use bare-metal servers over cloud-servers like Amazon EC2?

Also, I see the term on-prem servers a lot? Are they just bare-metal servers placed in an office as opposed to a remote location?

Comment: What is the business problem you’re trying to solve right now? Cost? Availability? Performance? Security? Regulatory compliance? Each of the three alternatives intersects with these concerns a little differently.

Comment: @J_H Can there be hypervisor based virtualization in on-premise servers? or are they always bare-metal?

Comment: What *business* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am trying to understand the difference between various server terms,

Comment: That would seem to be off-topic here unless you have an actual software problem that means you need to choose between those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't quite have the right terms.

1. Bare metal server : an actual computer you can touch running a single OS.
2. Virtual server : Software running on a bare metal server which pretends to be a server. eg VirtualBox this allows multiple "virtual servers" to run on the same hardware.
3. Cloud server : A virtual server provided by a company over the internet. "in the cloud" ie EC2 instances
4. On prem server : a server which runs on premises that you own. It might be bare metal or virtual

Normally the term "bare metal" is used to indicate that a program is not running on a virtual server, which might introduce a performance hit. ie "the database is running on bare metal"

You really need to to two comparisons,

- bare metal vs virtual
- cloud vs on prem

Comment: so virtual box based virtual servers are different from hypervisor based virtual servers?

Comment: VirtualBox _is_ a hypervisor.